# SAS Proc Freq Not Displaying Values

Tags: sas, frequency

I am doing some simple cross tabulations using Proc Freq, but I'm noticing that the output SAS gives me doesn't contain any frequency counts; I'm only getting percents.

Here is an example code that I ran in SAS (I am using SAS 9.4):

```
data test;
  input year 1-5 group $6;
cards;
2018 A
2018 A
2018 B
2018 B
2019 A
2019 A
2019 A
2019 B
;
run;

proc freq data = test;
  table year * group / norow nopercent;
run;
```

I'm expecting a table that has the frequency counts with the column percentage below, but instead, this is what SAS is giving me:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get the frequency values to be shown?

Comment: Well that is certainly unusual and not correct. Do you get the same result if you restart SAS ? Are you using a custom template or special ODS HTML options.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that leaves out frequencies.

Comment: I tried restarting SAS but still got the same results.  The computer I am using is brand new (I received it on Monday), so I haven't added any templates or options to it.  I will say that I ran similar code on my old computer (which was using SAS 9.3), and I did not get this error.

Comment: You posted a photograph of the ODS output. Perhaps your styles are messed up and the text is invisible?  What do you see in the plain text listing output?

Comment: When I unchecked "Create HTML" and checked "Create listing" on my preferences, I get the same results as in my original post but in the plain text.  It still only shows the percentages.

Comment: I would submit a ticket with SAS support (support.sas.com). Something is either amiss with your default settings, the installation itself, or you are missing crucial 9.3 hotfixes.

Comment: So it is not the STYLE from the ODS.  But it might be the TEMPLATE for PROC FREQ that is messed up.  Definitely check with SAS support as it does not look like a programming issue, but an installation/configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got this.  I reckon there is something you are not telling us.

[image]

Comment: The computer I am using is brand new (I received it on Monday), so I haven't added any templates or options to it.  I have run similar code on my old computer (which was using SAS 9.3), and I did not get this error.  My thought is that something happened when SAS 9.4 was installed on this computer, but I don't know what would cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help- I found the issue.  It looks like there was an issue with the cross-tab frequency template that came with SAS.  I was able to restore it by using the following code:

```
proc template;
    delete base.freq.crosstabfreqs;
run;
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I doubt that the installation was wrong. Something must have been run after installation that change the template. Make sure that you are not giving users write access to the system files of SAS. If you are using Unix then make sure you are not using the same account to run your SAS programs as was used to install it.

Comment: Agreed, should not have happened in a new installation. Something else must have happened to change it after the fact or some other setting overrides it - ie an autoexec that overwrites your templates for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

@_null_ your image is NOT the output I get when running the questions code.

The Frequency and Col Pct are NOT in row header cells, and instead are shown in a box offset to the left from the table.

[image]

Comment: That's the kind of table I was expecting to see.  I feel like some of the proc freq options/settings are not set properly on this machine for some reason.  I know there is a way to change proc freq formats, and even though I haven't made any changes to them, is there a way to restore default settings?

Comment: The output I am showing is from the SAS Report destination.

Comment: Gotcha.  Every destination has it's pros and cons.  My image was from a viewing of  the content produced by ODS HTML destination.